# How to see smtp server logs from cpanel

Tags: logging, smtp, cpanel

I asked a question in stackoverflow and they answered to check my smtp server logs. Is there any way to see smtp server logs from cpanel. If so then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to check the mail server logs through cPanel, You will have root access to check server logs file.